# Update statement from a list in same table SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update records

```
Update Contacts
Set company = '' 
Where company` in
```

the following list

```
Select top 100 company
From Contacts 
Where count(company) > 20
Group by company 
Order by count(*) desc
```

But I cannot get syntax to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must use `having` with an aggregate function like `count()`.

```
UPDATE Contacts
    SET company = ''
    WHERE company IN (
        SELECT TOP 100 company
             FROM Contacts                 
             GROUP BY company
             HAVING count(company) > 20
             ORDER BY count(company) DESC
    );
```

Comment: dang.. beat me by 2 seconds :)